# How to save strings in matrixes in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, cell

I want to have a matrix/cell, that has strings inside that I can access and use later as strings.

For instance, I have one variable (`MyVar`) and one cell (`site`) with names inside:

```
MyVar=-9999;
site={'New_York'; 'Lisbon'; 'Sydney'};
```

Then I want to do something like:

```
SitePosition=strcat(site{1},'_101'}
```

and then do this

```
save(sprintf('SitePosition%d',MyVar),);
```

This doesn't work at all! Is there a way to have strings in a matrix and access them in order to keep working with them if they were a string?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
MyVar=-9999; site={'New_York'; 'Lisbon'; 'Sydney'};
SitePosition = strcat(site{1},'_101');
save(sprintf('SitePosition%d',MyVar));
```

Works fine and yields `SitePosition-9999.mat`, note the syntax changes in lines 2 and 3.

Is there something else you're expecting?

EDIT: Based on your comment

Check out the documentation for [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#btppzj8-1) regarding saving specific variables

New example:

```
MyVar=-9999; 
site={'New_York'; 'Lisbon'; 'Sydney'};
SitePosition = strcat(site{1},'_101');
save(SitePosition,'MyVar');
```

Creates `New_York_101.mat` with only the variable `MyVar` in it.

Comment: Sorry, my example was stupid. I just realized after run the code... The way that i presented is not good to express my issue. But "kmoe", thanks for your comment. What I really want to do is, having 'SitePosition' as a variable, so the result in the end will be: "NewYork_101.mat", with the value of -9999 stored inside it; "Lisbon_101.mat", with the value of -9999 stored inside it; "Sydney_101.mat", with the value of -9999 stored inside it;